# Plotting boxplot using numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, boxplot

i have 2 numpy arrays x and y, x containg features and y containg the labels

```
x.shape
(1437, 9)
y.shape
(1437,)
```

I want to plot the box plot of the features to analyse the distributions of the features compared to the labels I used

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x=x,y=y,palette="Set3")
```

but i keep getting the error  **ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)**

Comment: try this:`ax = sns.boxplot(x=x[0],y=y,palette="Set3")`

Comment: Grouper and axis must be same length